# JmDNS - Register the same service in multiple machines

Tags: java, zeroconf, jmdns

I am using JmDNS to register a service in a couple o machines that are under the same subnet in my network. However, every time that a second machine goes up and tries to register the service, its name is automatically changed to something like "service_name (number)". I think that happens so the name of the service can remain unique in the network, and there's no conflict when resolving it. However, I was thinking if there is no way to register the service in the network with the same name and group the IP addresses of the machines that are responsible for that same service. For instance: I have three machines in my network, and all of them are going to provide the service X. So when they register the service, instead of having service X changing its name to "X (2)", and "X (3)", they all remain "X" but they are seem as a group of machines or IPs that are providing the same service "X".

I know that I can use the service listener and do something like regular expression check, if the name of the service is somehow related to "X", like "X (2)" then I add its IP address to my map. But I wanted to do this using only the library (if possible of course), and not manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to set X as the computer name, all under service Y.  [Apple's Bonjour naming convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/domainnames.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002460-SW1) is pretty helpful.

Here is a snapshot (using a bonjour browser) of what a tree of devices on the same network. Notice how each device has it's own name, and Ip. Also, you can set specific id (or other properties) so as to identify each device more easily.

[image]